# Can we set multiple DCM_SpecificCharacterSet while importing records using DICOM?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, dicom

Currently, I am using the below code to set parameters to retrieve data from PACS.

```
DcmDataset findParams = DcmDataset();
 findParams.putAndInsertString(DCM_QueryRetrieveLevel, "SERIES");
 findParams.putAndInsertString(DCM_SpecificCharacterSet, "ISO_IR 192");
```

However, just wanted to check can we provide support multiple characters set to import data  at the same time, Code will look like something below, I am trying to check whether this is possible or not  as I dont have the facility to verify the same.

```
 findParams.putAndInsertString(DCM_SpecificCharacterSet, "ISO_IR 192" ,"ISO_IR 100");
```

Comment: That will not work in DICOM. Multi-valued character sets are allowed, but there are several restrictions, one being that some character sets (including UTF-8, e.g. ISO_IR 192), cannot be combined with other encodings. The second problem is that even with multiple encodings, the encoding has to be switched in the encoded strings themselves (using defined escape sequences), so you would have to change all encoded strings.

Comment: Thanks @MrBeanBremen, Now I am pretty much scared if I allow a Latin character set only for some specific cases, how much code base will change.

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you want to express is that "this Query SCU can accept responses in the following character sets". This is plainly not possible. See a [discussion in the DICOM newsgroup](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.protocols.dicom/c/TTL-DeQwIdc/m/I-cU7fiLBAAJ) for reference. It ends with a proposal to add character set negotiation to the association negotiation. But such a supplement has not been submitted yet, and I am not aware of anyone working on it currently.

The semantics of the attribute `Specific Character Set (0008,0005)` in the context of the Query Retrieve Service Class:

**PS3.4, C.4.1.1.3.1 Request Identifier Structure**

> Conditionally, the Attribute Specific Character Set (0008,0005). This Attribute shall be included if expanded or replacement character sets may be used in any of the Attributes in the Request Identifier. It shall not be included otherwise

I.e. it describes nothing but the character encoding of your request dataset.

and
**C.4.1.1.3.2 Response Identifier Structure**

> Conditionally, the Attribute Specific Character Set (0008,0005). This Attribute shall be included if expanded or replacement character sets may be used in any of the Attributes in the Response Identifier. It shall not be included otherwise. The C-FIND SCP is not required to return responses in the Specific Character Set requested by the SCU if that character set is not supported by the SCP. The SCP may return responses with a different Specific Character Set.

I.e. you cannot control the character set in which the SCP will send you the responses. Surprising but a matter of fact.

Sending multiple values for the attribute is possible but has different semantics. It means that the request contains characters from different character sets which are switched using Code Extension Techniques as defined in ISO 2022. An illustrative example how this would look like and what it would mean is found in PS3.5, H.3.2

What implementors usually do to avoid character set compatibility issues is configuring "the one and only" character set for a particular installation (=hospital) in a locale configuration that is configured upon system setup. It works pretty well, for e.g. an installation in Russia will very likely support Cyrillic (ISO_IR 144) or UNICODE (ISO_IR 192) or both. In case of "both", you can select the character set that you prefer for configuring your system.